# How many hours have passed

Tags: php, date, datetime

This question has been asked in a one form or another but people have always been after an answer to how many days / hours / minutes / seconds have passed. My question is different and yes I have reviewed other questions. I am working on a coding task that part of requires me to work out how many hours (just hours not mins/secs) have passed since the last sign in. So if an employee signs in at say 9am and then leaves early at 4:30pm that would be 7.5 hours which I'd then use a SQL statement to store in a table.

How would I go about calculating the total hours passed? I have tried the following but I'm really not good with these things:-

```
$start_time = "0900";
$now = date("Hi");
$total_hours = $now - $start_time / 60;
```

As I said this just gave me 524 but now idea if that was right or if that needs to be converted by division or something.

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you use Carbon - A simple PHP API extension for DateTime. http://carbon.nesbot.com/#gettingstarted

Comment: I suggest you take the end timestamp - start timestamp to get total diff in seconds.. then just divide it with 3600 - Just like @Mircha now just answered. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you initialize two string variables that are converted to integers by PHP when you make a subtraction.

You could use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to get the time difference in hours.

```
$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Hi', '0900', $timeZone);
$end = new DateTime('now', $timeZone);
$interval = $start->diff($end);
echo $interval->format('%h hours');
```

Comment: How would I achieve this though? See I'm not storing the time in the database as a normal unix timestamp. I'm trying to make it as simple as possible by storing timeIn as date("Hi") and then the dateIn as date("d-m-y"). The start time for employees is obviously 9am which is stored as "0900". Date and Time functions have always kinda confused me when it comes to the maths side of things which is and never will be my strong point.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to actually store the full timestamp in the DB. Otherwise you will run into trouble if someone clocks in one day and clocks out the next (burning the midnight oil).

Comment: @postrel Thank you very much! That worked perfectly! Much appreciated!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ahh yeah see this is just a short coding task and the assumption written down is that the employee finishes at no later than 1730 hours or 5:30pm. Already been told I can make this assumption and create the simple clock in / clock out system as such. The idea was that this wouldn't be a complicated task.

Comment: @Dave You are welcome. If you want to keep your design, make sure to initialize the $start in the correct format that takes the date in cosideration, not just time. E.g. `DateTime::createFromFormat('HidmY', '090018062016', $timeZone);`

Comment: @Dave, I'd probably still prefer saving it as a timestamp. You can easily convert that back to the format you want if you want to display it elsewhere. E.g. `date('Hi', $timestamp)` or by using `from_unixtime` if you want to do it in MySQL.

Comment: I agree with @Mischa, **timestamp** is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Unix timestamp (number of seconds since 1/1/1970) to store the last login. Subtract the last login timestamp from the current timestamp and divide that by 3600 seconds to get the number of hours.

```
$total_hours = (time() - $last_login) / 3600;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with the code:

1. `$now - $start_time / 60` doesn't get evaluated the way you are expecting, the division operator has higher [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than the substraction operator

   - you need to use parentheses to enforce the order, like so: `($now - $start_time) / 60`
2. it doesn't make sense to divide the result by 60 since it's not in minutes, but rather a string in a HHMM format

---

Can't you store the login times as timestamps or datetime columns instead? It would be much easier to work with.

Anyway, to do do this properly (in this case), I'd use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$start_time = "0900";

$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Hi', $start_time);
$now = new DateTime('NOW');
$diff = $start->diff($now);
$total_hours = ($diff->h * 3600 + $diff->i * 60 + $diff->s) / 3600 * ($diff->invert ? -1 : 1);

var_dump($total_hours);
```

This code prints the number of hours (as a float) since the `$start_time`. If will be negative if *NOW* is before the `$start_time`.

If it's *14:51:44*, the result will be:

```
float(5.8622222222222)
```

If it's *05:20:31*, the result will be:

```
float(-3.6580555555556)
```

Comment: I suppose I could yes, however not sure how to store as a timestamp. This is all so confusing to me. This task I have to do is literally only to gage where I am in terms of my PHP coding abilities as the company I'm to go work for wants to train me up anyway.

Comment: See the docs for date and time types of MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html